# When iterating through has_many, the result shows the whole array not only the requested column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have this code:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :residents, through: :owners
end

class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :properties, through: :owners
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :resident
    belongs_to :property
end
```

and default generated controllers.

I searched for how to list data from `has_many through` relationships and it works for me, but don't know why it also shows the whole array.

Here is the view code:

```
 <tbody>

    <% @residents.each do |resident| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= resident.name %></td>
        <td><%= resident.birthdate %></td>
        <td><%= resident.birthId %></td>
        <td><%= resident.address %></td>
        <td><%= resident.email %></td>
        <td><%= resident.tel %></td>
        <td><%= resident.properties.each do |property| %>
            <%= property.name %>
          <% end %> 
        </td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

and when I show the data from that iteration it shows the column, in this the "case name", and in `[]` the whole array like this:

```
Dostojevskeho 15 
[#<Property id: 2, name: "Dostojevskeho 15", registerNumber: "9845", propertyList: 6977, propertyType: 8, created_at: "2016-01-09 20:20:04", updated_at: "2016-01-09 20:20:04">]
```

[image]

I can't find what am I doing wrong. When I compared it to all tutorials my view looks fine to me.

This is part of the residents controller with index and show:

```
class ResidentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_resident, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @residents = Resident.all
  end
 def show
    @residents = Resident.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: Use singular of the word `@resident` in your show action, show is for one particular record, like in your code found by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
<%= resident.properties.each do |property| %>
```

to this:

```
<% resident.properties.each do |property| %>
```

Removing the `=` tells Rails that you only want to iterate over the `resident.properties`. Otherwise you get this weird behavior, where Rails is trying to print the iterator itself onto the page - which is rarely what you want.